# How to index a matrix with the column maxima of other matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have 2 matrices `A` and `B`.

I find the max values in the columns of A, and keep their indices in I. So far so good.
Now, I need to choose those arrays of B with the same index as stored in I. I don't know how to do this.
See below:

```
A = [1,2,3; 0,8,9]
B = [0,1,2; 4,2,3]
[~,I] = max(A)
h = B(I)
```

I need to get these values of `B`:

```
h = [0 2 3]
```

But the code results in a different one. How can I fix it?

```
A =

 1     2     3
 0     8     9


B =

 0     1     2
 4     2     3


I =

 1     2     2


h =

 0     4     4
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`max`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function how you used it works like

> If A is a matrix, then `max(A)` is a row vector containing the maximum value of each column.

so `M = max(A)` is equivalent to `M = max(A,[],1)`. But rather use the third input if you're not sure.

If you use `max` to find the **maxima in the columns** of the matrix, it returns the **row indices**. The **column indices** are for your case simply `1:size(A,2) = [1 2 3]`.

Now you need to convert your row and column indices to linear indices with [**`sub2ind`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
%// data
A = [1,2,3; 0,8,9]
B = [0,1,2; 4,2,3]

%// find maxima of each column in A
[~, I] = max( A, [], 1 )  %// returns row indices

%// get linear indices for both, row indices and column indices
I = sub2ind( size(A), I, 1:size(A,2) ) 

%// index B
h = B(I)
```

---

returns:

```
h =

     0     2     3
```